# How to shorten an arrow at the end?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I want to draw the coil line in direction of the red points, but they shouldn't surpass the circle. Is it possible to just shorten the length of the arrow to the radius of the circle?

[image: Example]

My Code:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    %Left
    \node (m_1) at (-3.5,1) [middle] {};
    \node (c_1) at (-3.5,1) [circle,draw=black, style=dashed, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4cm] {};
    
    \node (sim1_1) at (-1,2) [sim] {};
    \node (sim2_1) at (-4,4) [sim] {};
    \node (sim3_1) at (-6,-0.5) [sim] {};
    \node (sim4_1) at (-1.5,-1) [sim] {};
    \node (dissim1_1) at (-4,-0.5) [dissim] {};
    \node (dissim2_1) at (-3,-1.5) [dissim] {};
    \node (dissim3_1) at (-4.5,2) [dissim] {};
    \node (dissim4_1) at (-3,2) [dissim] {};
    \node (dissim5_1) at (-1,0.5) [dissim] {};
    
    
    \node (m_2) at (3.5,1) [middle] {};
    \node (c_2) at (3.5,1) [circle,draw=black, style=dashed, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4cm] {};
    
    \node (sim1_2) at (6,2) [sim] {};
    \node (sim2_2) at (3,4) [sim] {};
    \node (sim3_2) at (1,-0.5) [sim] {};
    \node (sim4_2) at (5.5,-1) [sim] {};
    \node (dissim1_2) at (7-4,-0.5) [dissim] {};
    \node (dissim2_2) at (7-3,-1.5) [dissim] {};
    \node (dissim3_2) at (7-4.5,2) [dissim] {};
    \node (dissim4_2) at (7-3,2) [dissim] {};
    \node (dissim5_2) at (7-1,0.5) [dissim] {};
    
    
    \draw[spring1] (m_1) -- (sim1_1);
    \draw[spring1] (m_1) -- (sim2_1);
    \draw[spring1] (m_1) -- (sim3_1);
    \draw[spring1] (m_1) -- (sim4_1);
    
    \draw[spring2] (m_2) -- (dissim1_2);
    \draw[spring2] (m_2) -- (dissim2_2);
    \draw[spring2] (m_2) -- (dissim3_2);
    \draw[spring2] (m_2) -- (dissim4_2);
    \draw[spring2] (m_2) -- (dissim5_2);
 
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Can you make the code compilable?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Extend your code fragment to small but complete document. We need information about your document preamble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use of the `intersections` Ti*k*kZ library and draw springs from circle center to intersections of paths from cener to selected nodes out of circle:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                intersections}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = {Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
   dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1, inner sep=2pt,
                 node contents={}},
 dot/.default = green,
middle/.style = {dot=blue!50, inner sep=3pt, node contents={}},
   decoration = {coil, segment length=4pt, pre length=8pt, post length=8pt}
                        ]
%Left
\node (m) at (-3.5,1) [middle];
\node (c) at (-3.5,1) [circle, draw, dashed, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4cm,
                         name path=C] {};

\node (sim1_1) at (-1,2)    [dot];
\node (sim2_1) at (-4,4)    [dot];
\node (sim3_1) at (-6,-0.5) [dot];
\node (sim4_1) at (-1.5,-1) [dot];
\node (dissim1_1) at (-4,-0.5)  [dot=red];
\node (dissim2_1) at (-4.5,2)   [dot=red];
\node (dissim3_1) at (-3,2)     [dot=red];
\node (dissim4_1) at (-3,-1.5)  [dot=red];
\node (dissim5_1) at (-1,0.5)   [dot=red];

    \foreach \i in {1,2,3} % nodes inside of circle
\draw[<->, decorate] (m) -- (dissim\i_1);

    \foreach \i [count=\j from 4] in {a,b} % nodes outside of circle
{
\path[name path=\i] (m) -- (dissim\j_1);
\draw[<->, decorate, name intersections={of=C and \i,by=s}] (m) -- (s);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]